# Avoid counting values of Ints with for loop in Kotlin

Tags: for-loop, kotlin, count

I have a list of A class objects

```
data class A{
  val abc: Abc
  val values: Int?
}

val list = List<A>
```

If I want to count how many objects I have in list I use:
`val count= a.count()` 
or `val count= a.count(it -> {})`

How to append all values in the list of objects A avoiding for loop? Generaly Im looking for proper kotlin syntax with avoiding code below

```
if (a!= null) {
  for (i in list) {
    counter += i.values!!
  }
}
```

Comment: `val list:A = ...` looks like you have only a single item of type `A` in the `val list`...

Comment: Edited, this was just a example code. Of course I mean a list :)

Comment: You're for loop could cause an `NPE` from your use of `!!`... beware using the `!!` operator, it can be avoided in most cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use [`sumBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html) or [`sum`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html) in case you have a list of non-nullable numbers already available, i.e.:

```
val counter = list.sumBy { it.values ?: 0 }
// or
val counter = extractedNonNullValues.sum()
```

The latter only makes sense if you already mapped your `A.values` before to a list of non-nullable values, e.g. something like:

```
val extractedNonNullValues= list.mapNotNull { it.values } // set somewhere else before because you needed it...
```

If you do not need such an intermediate `extractedNonNullValues`-list then just go for the `sumBy`-variant.

Comment: Thank you :) I don't know how but somehow I forgot about sum function haha :D

Comment: Calling `mapNotNull` before sum will cause the list to be iterated once to create a new list and then the new list will be iterated to get the sum, not really a good idea. `sumBy` will iterate only once. Sure, you could turn the list into a sequence and the combine `mapNotNull` with `sum`, but it's redundant in this case.

Comment: of course... this should be kept in mind, when using the second variant... I think the second variant comes in handy if the list was already filtered or mapped to non-null-values (i.e. assigned to some intermediate variable)... then you know there is also `sum` available for such cases... in this particular example it doesn't make much sense to use it...

Comment: Your answer gives 2 possible solutions, one of which is less than optimal which could confuse people?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you doing any appending to a list in the question. Based on your for loop I believe what you meant  was "How do I sum properties of objects in my list". If that's the case you can use `sumBy`, the extension function on list that takes a `labmda: ((T) -> Int)` and returns an `Int` like so:

```
val sum = list.sumBy { a -> a.values ?: 0 }
```

Also, calling an `Int` property `values` is pretty confusing, I think it should be called `value`. The plural indicates a list...

On another note, there is a possible `NPE` in your original for loop. Avoid using `!!` on nullable values as, if the value is null, you will get an `NPE`. Instead, use null coalescing (aka elvis) operator to fall back to a default value `?:` - this is perfectly acceptable in a sum function. If the iteration is not to do with summing, you may need to handle the null case differently.

Comment: Thank you so much for answer. I totally forgot about sum function :D. I marked Roland answer as "accepted" cause he was 1 minute earlier. Seems fair. Thank you :)

Comment: I will take a note. Thanks once again! :)